# Run Scaffold-DbContext on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I have a site that was built using database first and I'm trying to continue development of it on a mac.  Normally I would run the Scaffold-dbContext using the Console Package Manager in Visual Studio.  The mac version doesn't have this I tried running it in Terminal, but that obviously didn't work.  Is it possible to run this command, or do I need to continue development on Windows?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? Same problem..

Comment: No, I just went back to developing on Windows.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm using High Sierra 10.13.5 and VS Community 7.5.3 (build 7).

I'm added the entry:

DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0"

on .csproj, opened de solution and restored NuGet packages.

But it did't added on my project and the Console is unable to write any word.

Some idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the code work for me on visual studio mac

Install the below package using visual studio mac edit references on project or add package to .csproj file.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

or using the **Terminal** navigate to the project and use the below command -

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

Now check the tools and EF are installed or not.Navigate to the project install location and use mac terminal with below command. It should show entity framework details

```
dotnet ef
```

Now Scaffold the DB context

```
dotnet ef dbcontext Scaffold "Server=<servername>,1433;Initial Catalog=<dbName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<userID>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o <directory name>
```

References

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer.  This wasn't possible when I first asked the question, but with the update to .Net Core 2.0, this answer gives all the necessary info and steps required to do this on a mac.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57070108/266553 - `dotnet ef` is now a separate tool, `dotnet-ef`. Also, in the scaffold command there should be a space between the closing quote and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Comment: The above command work for me after using this command `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef` ... I already installed this ... but didn't work until run with the --global flag...

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon - you are abs right, that is why the answer must NOT be marked as correct.

Answer (score 7):

You can run the command from the terminal after completing a few required steps as found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet):

1. You need to add the following manually to your *.csproj

```html
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

2. Execute

> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

3.Execute

> dotnet restore

You should now be able to scaffold using the command:

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold --help

Comment: With the updated to .Net Core 2.0 this can finally be done.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to post my solution after I struggled for a while. Had to separate the schema string into multiple --schema options.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=<servername>,1433;Initial Catalog=<dbName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<userID>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --context [context] -f --output-dir [dir] --schema [schema1] --schema [schema2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET Core 3.0.0 even after installing EntityFrameworkCore you will need to run

`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`