# Command dotnet ef not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0

I'm following [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-3.0#create-an-initial-migration) in order to create an initial migration. When I execute `dotnet`, I get the help section, meaning that the PATH works properly.

Then I try to execute the command below from the docs in console window:

> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate

I get the following error:

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
> Possible reasons for this include:

- You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
- You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
- You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
- I excluded the first item since I copied the command.
- I excluded the second item because the package *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* is installed.
- I excluded the third item because I get the help section when invoking *dotnet*.

I'm googling the issue but since the version is new, there's not much to go on and/or it's drowning in similar issues from earlier versions.

I tried to forcibly install *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore* just in case it needs to be explicitly added. I ran into the error message telling me that the latest version to pick from is 2.2.6 and a downgrade is a no-go. I'm not sure how to install the version compatible with the SQL-package I have on my system already (and even less certain if that's right approach to kill this issue).

> Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10 to 2.2.6. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
> Web ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10 ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10 ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10)
> Web -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.6)

Answer (score 1014, accepted):

To install the `dotnet-ef` tool, run the following command:

.*NET 8*

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 8.*
```

.*NET 7*

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.*
```

.*NET 6*

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.*
```

*.NET 5*

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.*
```

*.NET Core 3*

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.*
```

---

For more information about the history of `dotnet-ef`, see the [announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-4/) for ASP.NET Core 3 Preview 4, which explains that this tool was changed from being built-in to requiring an explicit install:

> #### The dotnet ef tool is no longer part of the .NET Core SDK
>
> This change allows us to ship `dotnet ef` as a regular .NET CLI tool that can be installed as either a global or local tool.

Comment: After installing the tool... same error. When try to re-install `Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.`. Yet running `dotnet ef` results in the error in the OP

Comment: @DouglasGaskell That usually means it's a path issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60938208/2630078.

Comment: To keep this answer valid for future, i think we should modify the answer for .net 8 to:
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 8.*

Answer (score 37):

If you are using a Dockerfile for deployments these are the steps you need to take to resolve this issue.

Change your Dockerfile to include the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
ENV PATH $PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef --version 3.1.1
```

Also change your `dotnet ef` commands to be `dotnet-ef`

Comment: In case still, the PATH doesn't work, use ENV directive like this: ENV PATH $PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools

Answer (score 35):

I solved this problem by installing *dotnet-f tool* locally with the following commands.

**If you are setting up this repository**

```
dotnet new tool-manifest

dotnet tool install --local dotnet-ef --version 5.0.6
```

Then use **dotnet dotnet-ef** instead of **dotnet-ef**.

Comment: Please note that the question is a bit dated and at the time of it's creation, the considered version was .NET Core 3.x whereas your solution suggests .NET Core 5 (or rather .NET 5 or whatever MS calls it this week). I still appreciate your answer (hence the upvote) and I'd like it to stay. Just making a remark for the future, sloppy reader.

Comment: I am using .net 7 and this worked the other way for .net 7 did not and that is on their documentations

Comment: I'm using mac and thats worked me.

Comment: I'm using github codespace and that's worked me .

Answer (score 19):

> Global tools can be installed in the default directory or in a
>   specific location. The default directories are:
>
> - Linux/macOS  --->  $HOME/.dotnet/tools
> - Windows     --->  %USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools
>
> If you're trying to run a global tool, check that the PATH environment variable on your machine contains the path where you installed the global tool and that the executable is in that path.

[Troubleshoot .NET Core tool usage issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues)

Comment: This was my problem, when I installed on MacOS via "dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef" I got a prompt to close and reopen the terminal window so that the new configuration would take effect, but in fact the default installation folder $HOME/.net/tools had not been added to the PATH variable.

Comment: I am glad it helped you :)

Comment: Why does a global install put things in $HOME? And why doesn't it tell you that you need to augment you PATH? It's barmy...

Answer (score 13):

For everyone using .NET Core CLI on [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) [MSYS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#History):

After installing using

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

add this line to to the *bashrc* file (`C:\msys64\home\username\` - .bashrc (the location depends on your setup)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/username/.dotnet/tools
```

Comment: This answer does not tackle the problem the OP has. Please consider answering the general question, while also introducing this specific way of solving the issue.

Comment: OP does not explain its environment. A "console window" could use many environment.

Comment: This works for Ubuntu as well. I'm surprised this is not documented anywhere

Answer (score 9):

This will work for me on Visual studio code, in Ubuntu

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet tool restore
```

After that all the execution are done like

```
dotnet tool run dotnet-ef
```

or

```
dotnet dotnet-ef
```

Comment: Firstly You should create manifest : `dotnet new tool-manifest` and then `dotnet tool install --local dotnet-ef`

Answer (score 8):

Run PowerShell or a command prompt as administrator and run the below command.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.3
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [Snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager)) package dotnet-sdk on Linux, this can be resolved by updating your *~.bashrc* file / etc. as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DOTNET_ROOT=/snap/dotnet-sdk/current
export MSBuildSDKsPath=$DOTNET_ROOT/sdk/$(${DOTNET_ROOT}/dotnet --version)/Sdks
export PATH="${PATH}:${DOTNET_ROOT}"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "/ etc"? [et cetera](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/etc.#Phrase)? Or the directory `/ etc`? Or something else? In any case, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it may occur due to different users within a system.

So to resolve the problem, you can install the dotnet-ef locally in your solution rather than adding it globally.

Steps to install locally.

1. Create a local manifest file via
   `dotnet new tool-manifest`
2. Go to the `config` folder:

   `cd .\.config`
3. Install the tool via
   `dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --version versionNumber`. It'll be successfully installed and its commands will be accessible within the project.

Comment: I suggest that you check the existing answers before posting an own. The issue is due to an early stage of the version (check the date of the post).

Comment: thanks for the information, but this problem occurred recently with me using .net 5 and this was the only solution I found, so it may help someone.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is - The `dotnet ef` tool is no longer part of the .NET Core SDK in ASP.NET Core 3.0.

Solution: Install `dotnet ef` as a global tool

Steps:

1. Run PowerShell or command prompt as Administrator in the project root
2. Run below command.

For the latest version:

```html
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

For a specific version:

```html
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version <<version_number>>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem on **ubuntu**.

First install dotnet-ef

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.0
```

**Then you need to add path to bashrc.**

Open bashrc:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add following:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"
```

Then execute this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem after I installed the dotnet-ef tool using Ansible with [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) escalated privilege on Ubuntu. I had to add **become: no** for the Playbook task, and then the dotnet-ef tool became available to the current user.

```
  - name: install dotnet tool dotnet-ef
    command: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version {{dotnetef_version}}
    become: no
```

Comment: Where should it go? For example, a file? What is the name of the file? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you ask yourself what versions are available:

**Versions tab** on this page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ef/

Besides that as others already mentioned it's:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.11
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by uninstalling all the versions on my PC and then reinstalling `dotnet`.

Comment: Better suited as a comment. Should explain how to resolve and why with resources

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps, and it worked fine for me:

1. Add a source:

   ```
   dotnet nuget add source --name nuget.org https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
   ```
2. Run the installation command line:

   ```
   dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.6
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I received a 401 Unauthorized when trying to install dotnet ef.

In the end, I found another link [Telerik resolution](https://www.telerik.com/forums/failed-to-retrieve-https-nuget-telerik-com-v3-package-dotnet-ef-index-json-when-trying-to-update-dotnet-ef#:%7E:text=Tool%20%27dotnet-ef%27%20failed%20to%20update%20due%20to%20the,was%20found%2C%20but%20it%20was%20not%20a.NET%20tool.) that helped.

Summed up, using Visual Studio 2022, the steps needed was:

1. remove the Telerik source from Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Source
2. run this command to add the source and force it to use provided credentials:

***dotnet nuget add source "https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json" -u "username" -p "password" -store-password-in-clear-text***

Then I could continue to follow Kirk's steps and install dotnet ef

Note:
Not ideal to use -store-password-in-clear-text, but there was another issue with encrypted credentials. So for now just used that

Comment: I can't imagine how that's relevant approach to resolving that error. Telerik is a 3rd party supplier for some component for GUIs, aren't they?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what went wrong. One of the other messages I received when trying to install EF was:

Failed to retrieve information about 'donet-ef' from remote source 'https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/package/dotnet-ef/index.json'

So there was definately an issue with the Nuget sources (brand new install on a new laptop...thus the need to reinstall EF)

I tried various other solutions, but the only one that worked was the Telerik resolution linked in my first post.

Comment: Exciting... It seem, though, that there's something with the NuGet repositories on your local environment. I haven't ever-ever got anything with Telerik during so many years, so I'm pretty certain it's unrelated in a general sense.