# Could not add a migration in ef

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to add a migration in a Visual Code in ef using the following syntax:

```
dotnet ef migrations add A_isVerified
```

All I get is this:

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
> Possible reasons for this include:   * You misspelled a built-in
> dotnet command.   * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but
> dotnet-ef does not exist.   * You intended to run a global tool, but a
> dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the
> PATH.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Did you check if a PATH contains the default directory?

Comment: Which version of dotnet are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066856/dotnet-ef-not-found-in-net-core-3

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` as a package in your project. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef
```