# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design disappearing/not being detected when attempting to scaffold from a database in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I'd like to scaffold a number of tables from an existing database to work with them in a .NET Core 3.0 Web API. Under previous versions of .NET Core, having references to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` has been sufficient when scaffolding from this database. However, in .NET Core 3.0, when I attempt to scaffold from my database, the following sequence of events happens

- The command prompt hangs
- The references to the necessary NuGet packages (most notably `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`) disappear in the Solution Explorer for my project in Visual Studio
- I get the error message `Your startup project '[project name]' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again`

To scaffold, I'm running the following command

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "[connection string]" microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver`

Connection string omitted since it's very likely not related to the issue.

I've installed Entity Framework as a global tool, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57070108/4346183), as well as adding package references to the 3 aforementioned NuGet packages, as well as `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`, within my project.

What do I need to do differently in order to get these tables to scaffold correctly?

Comment: I have the same problem.