# dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0 on MAC causes unknown Nuget Error

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.0

After upgrading to .Net Core 3.1 in my Web API Project I tried this usual ef command -

```
dotnet ef
```

Got:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.

Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Then found this - [dotnet ef not found in .NET Core 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066856/dotnet-ef-not-found-in-net-core-3)

Therefore, tried:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0
```

and got:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v2/index.json 
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). 
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by: ...
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this  -

[Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source/58851687#58851687)

So, then opened Nuget.config on MAC -

```
~/.nuget/Nuget/Nuget.config
```

And deleted all the URLs from in there.

Re-running

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0
```

Worked :)

On re-using NUGET in a VS for MAC project (just added any Nuget), I was just left with

```
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Finally, realised had used ef tools 3.0.0, so finished updating ef tools with -

dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef

Comment: For Windows VS2019, you can do: tools | options | nuget pacakage manager | package sources UI to uncheck/disable that package feed