# dotnet-ef does not recognises .net sdks linux mint / ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, entity-framework, ubuntu

I have installed dotnet sdk6 and sdk7 with corresponding runtimes, from microsoft packages designed for ubuntu/linux mint. I have installed global version of dotnet-ef from nuget packages, but it seems that is could not find the existing .net sdks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install dotnet tools package. you can take help from the following link : 
[Command dotnet ef not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066856/command-dotnet-ef-not-found)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.